# How to "expand" RichTextBox Paragraph's background color?

Tags: c#, wpf

As you can see below, there are white margins from both sides, how to expand the gray background horizontally, so it will cover the `TextBox` from edge to edge?

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="logTextBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="12"  Margin="10,165,10,10" >
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="480" />
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Usage:

```
    public void AddLog(string log)
    {
        Run run = new Run(log);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);
        paragraph.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        var numberOfBlocks = logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count;
        const int MaxNumberOfBlocks = 100;
        if (numberOfBlocks > MaxNumberOfBlocks)
        {
            logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(logTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
        }
        logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        logTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `PagePadding` property of the `FlowDocument` to `0` after the RichTextBox has been loaded:

```
public void AddLog(string log)
{
    Run run = new Run(log);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);
    paragraph.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    var numberOfBlocks = logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count;
    const int MaxNumberOfBlocks = 100;
    if (numberOfBlocks > MaxNumberOfBlocks)
    {
        logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(logTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
    }
    logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
    logTextBox.Document.PagePadding = new Thickness(0); //<--
    logTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
}
```